# bussproofs: How to make lines in the "prooftree" environment look thicker?

Tags: bussproofs

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage[fontsize=32pt]{fontsize}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$a < b$}
\AxiomC{$b < c$}
\BinaryInfC{$ a < c $}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting:

[image]

As you see, that the horizontal bar is thiner than the lines of the `<` and `>` symbols. The problem is that the weight of the bar is fixed, while the weight of the lines in the symbols depends on the font size. How can I change the thickness of the bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Not an answer, a comment with pictures :).
- The [CTAN entry](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bussproofs) contains an [example document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/bussproofs/testbp2.pdf).
- When you zoom into the [example document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/bussproofs/testbp2.pdf), then it looks different from your screenshot.
- In my PDF viewer, the line width varies a lot depending on the zoom level.
- Maybe this "discovery" helps.

[image]

---

I also tried `\solidLine` but with no visible effect on my end.
[image]

---

### Update

Chapter `5.3 Inference-line styles` sound promising, or not?

[image]

### Conclusion

In conclusion, the following part of the manual was crucial:

> "The default setting of `\ruleScoreFiller` is `{\hrule}`, and in LATEX
> an unqualified `\hrule`command produces a horizontal line of thickness
> 0.4 pt. **To change the rule’s thickness, use the command `\def\ruleScoreFiller{\hrule height new-thickness}`.**"

Comment: That's because the font is 11pt (or so) in the document :)

Comment: @yegor256 Did you have a look at **Chapter `5.3 Inference-line styles`**? I am not skilled enough to dig deeper but it sounds at least related. **See edit.**

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but the thickness is not changed :(

Comment: @yegor256 Going offline now but if I were you I would *add your attempt to change the line width to your MWE* so that others do not have to search the manual for longer than needed.

Comment: My bad, `\def\ruleScoreFiller{\hrule height 3pt}` works!

Comment: @yegor256 Great, good to hear!